# How do I retrieve a list of all checked items using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to change the function of [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox) AngularJS Example that syncs (`Using <input type="checkbox">`) to return an array of objects.

In my html I have the following code using ng-repeat and some function calls from the AngularJS demo example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="standard" flex="50">
      <label> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" /> {{item.name}} </label>
</div>
```

I also have a button to select or remove all checkbox entries:

```
 <label> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isChecked()" ng-click="toggleAll()" autofocus ng-model="checkbox" ng-change='delayedSearch(0)'/>
        <span ng-if="!isChecked()">all</span>
        <span ng-if="isChecked()">nothing</span>
  </label> <br><br>
```

In my controller I initialize array items as follows:

```
$scope.items = [{name:'K://',value:'nemo'},{name:'Bugzilla',value:'bugzilla'},{name:'Jira',value:'jira'}];
```

and the corresponding functions to interact with the checkboxes:

```
    $scope.toggle = function (item, list) {
            var idx = list.indexOf(item);
            if (idx > -1) {
                    list.splice(idx, 1);
                    if (list.length == 0){
                            list.push('nothing');
                    }
            }else {
                    var id = list.indexOf('nothing');
                    if (id > -1) {
                            list.splice(id,1);
                    }
                    list.push(item);
            }
    };

    $scope.exists = function (item, list) {
            return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
    };

    $scope.isChecked = function() {
            return $scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length;
    };

    $scope.toggleAll = function() {
            if ($scope.selected.length === $scope.items.length) {
                    $scope.selected = ['nothing'];
            } else if ($scope.selected.length === 0 || $scope.selected.length > 0) {
                    $scope.selected = $scope.items.slice();
            }
    };
```

Currently my code returns a list of objects of all checked items, for example:

```
[{"name":"K://","value":"nemo"},{"name":"Bugzilla","value":"bugzilla"},{"name":"Jira","value":"jira"}]
```

I would like to get a list of only the values of all items that are checked like this:

```
["nemo","bugzilla","jira"]
```

Comment: Why don't you push the values instead of the objects?

Comment: Then I get the correct result for single toggle but toggleall still returns objects

Comment: You can loop through or use the below answer to get all the values for toggle all

Comment: one last thing.. if my list is empty how can I set it to [{"name":"nothing","value":"nothing"}]?

Comment: `if (!list.length) { list.push({"name":"nothing","value":"nothing"}) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map results list like this:

```
   var valuesArray =  [{"name":"K://","value":"nemo"},{"name":"Bugzilla","value":"bugzilla"},{"name":"Jira","value":"jira"}].map(function(obj) {
      return obj.value;
    }); // ["nemo","bugzilla","jira"]
```

Comment: Map is a very strong little thing, solved all my issues thanks a lot